When having multiple type parameters, omit some but keep inference
Consider the following example
function createMyContext<T, N extends Capitalize<string>>(name: N) {
  const contextName = `${name}Provider` as const;
  const hookName = `use${name}` as const;
  // Some non relevant runtime logic here to create the context,
  return {
    [contextName]: {}, // the context,
    [hookName]: () => ({}) // the hook
  } as {[K in typeof contextName]: Provider<T>} & {[K in typeof hookName]: () => T};
}

This function is a helper to create a react context + relative hook giving it the type of the context value and the name. It will produce
const {UserProvider, useUser} = createMyContext<User, "User">("User");

Having to repeat "User" is not the most attractive thing I can think of.
BUT we need to pass the first type parameter, to tell ts what type our context needs and if we specify the first, we MUST specify the second as well.
In short, I only want to pass the first type parameter, omitting the second but keeping the type inference from the value passed to the function.
This is the best solution I've found:
function createMyContext<T>() {
  return function<N extends Capitalize<string>>(name: N) {
    const contextName = `${name}Provider` as const;
    const hookName = `use${name}` as const;
    // Some non relevant runtime login here to create the context,
    return {
      [contextName]: {}, // the context,
      [hookName]: () => ({}) // the hook
    } as {[K in typeof contextName]: Provider<T>} & {[K in typeof hookName]: () => T};
  }
}

const {UserProvider, useUser} = createMyContext<User>()("User");

The double call is ugly and useless. I don't like the idea of creating two functions just for a static typing need. Is there a prettier way to achieve this that I didn't think of?
Playground link

How do you define the returned hook? Essentially, where does type User come into play?

You can see it in the return signature. When creating a react context, unless you give it a default value, which is not the case here, you need to pass a generic type to it in order to declare what value that context accepts.

Do you plan to implement the ability to pass a default value?

As stated in the previous comment, I don't

You could make a single generic type that accepts and includes the name, which the factory name param pulls out (still needs you to include the name twice, but now on different lines. 3% less ugly). Playground.
A slightly better approach is to accept a parameter and cast its type on call. Playground. If you like either approach (more likely the second one), let me know and I'll add it as the answer.

Unfortunately without partial type argument inference as in ms/TS#26242, you need to work around it. If you think currying is ugly and useless, I doubt you'll like the other workaround which is when you add a dummy function parameter. Essentially this is a missing feature so you have to pick the thing you dislike the least and uses it. See the linked q/a for more information.

Thank you for pointing to the related issue. This solves my doubts.
